# if statement not returning anything

Tags: ios, string, if-statement, cocos2d-iphone

**FULL CLASS CODE HERE:** http://pastebin.com/rdjDGLJS

EDIT: Latest code snippet taken from original posters comment

```
NSMutableString *spriteType;


- (void) pickSpriteType {

    randomSpriteNumber = arc4random() % 2+1;

    switch (randomSpriteNumber) {
        case 1:
            spriteType = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"typeOne"];
            break;

        case 2:
            spriteType = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"typeTwo"];
            break;
    }
}


- (void) findSpriteNumber {

    levelNumberString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%d",levelNumber];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"plist_enemies" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    spriteNumber = [[[dict objectForKey:spriteType] objectForKey:levelNumberString] intValue];
}


- (void) initSprite {
    [self moveUp];
    for(int i = 0; i<spriteNumber; i++) {
        if ([spriteType isEqualToString:@"typeOne"]) {
            NSLog(@"repeat");
        }
        if ([spriteType isEqualToString:@"typeTwo"]) {
            NSLog(@"repeat");
        }
    }
}
```

ORIGINAL POST:

I am using an if statement with an NString using the following code:

```
- (void) initSprite {
    for(int i = 0; i<spriteNumber; i++) {
        if (spriteType == @"typeOne") {
            NSLog(@"repeat");
        }   
    }  
}
```

It should be logging "repeat" 'spriteNumber' amount of times, as long as the string 'spriteType' has the contents of 'typeOne', but nothing happens. It does not log "repeat", but neither does it have any errors. The contents of the string 'sprite type' is definitely,  'typeOne', and spriteNumber > 0.

What can be done to fix this issue?

**EDIT**: I have now tried the code like this:

```
- (void) initSprite {
for(int i = 0; i<spriteNumber; i++) {
if ([spriteType isEqualToString:@"typeOne"]) {
    NSLog(@"repeat");
}}}
```

It returns an error, EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Are you sure you posted the code correctly?  It is missing brackets around `[spriteType isEqualToString:@"typeOne"]`

Comment: @borrrden well seen, I posted it with the wring code, im editing it know.

Comment: @akuritsu, can u trace spriteType is in your memory or not.... EXC_BAD_ACCESS happen only your object is not in memory then also u trying to access it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Re. retaining the value of spriteType.

It looks as if you are attempting to use spriteType as a class variable BUT you do not retain it when you set it's value.

```
spriteType = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"typeOne"];
```

**stringWithFormat:** will return an autoreleased NSString which will not be accessible outside of the scope of the method in which it is called.

The easiest way to get spriteType to work across the whole of your class is to declare it as a @property - In both cases you will need to declare the property in your .h file & synthesise it in your .m file.

ARC

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* spriteType;

NON ARC - *you will be responsible for releasing the value in dealloc*

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* spriteType;

ORIGINAL:

Using == on an NSString will test if the two instances of string are indeed the same (*pointer equivalence*).

You need to use the NSString method **isEqualToString:** to test for *object equivalence* like this -

```
if ([spriteType isEqualToString:@"typeOne"])
```

**isEqualToString:** tests the contents of the string variables against each other....

Comment: That compiles fine, but when I run the method, it gives me an error. EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: That is another problem.  The code above is absolutely correct.  You probably overreleased `spriteType` but without code it is impossible to tell.

Comment: "mean they are never the same" <- that statement isn't accurate. If both strings are const strings then pointer equivalence will work.

Comment: RE: NSMutableString *spriteType; how is this declared and initialised? i.e. show any/all iVar & property declarations and show how you initialise it before it gets used in -(void)initSprite.

Comment: At the moment there are no other property declaration or anything. It is used in the -(void)pickSpriteType method then to read the plist, and then -(void)initSprite

Answer (score 5):

I've waited a long time for a reason to use this silly story that I came up with regarding the two types of equals in the programming world.  Imagine that you and your significant other go on a picnic together.  You are deeply in love so you pack one lunch for both of you to share.  If someone were to ask you to point to your lunch, you would both point to the same lunch.  Your lunches are `==` to each other.  Now let's say you are big eaters and so you pack two different lunches with identical content.  Now when someone asks you to point to your lunch, you will point to different lunches.  Your lunches are `!=`.  However, if you look INSIDE the lunch at what kind of food is inside, they still have the same content.  They are `[isEqualTo]` each other.  Do you see where I am going with this?

The lunch is an object, and you and your significant other are pointers.  You tester for *pointer equivalence* (i.e. which lunch is it) when you use `==`, but that is not usually what you want.  You want *object equivalence* (i.e. the food in your lunch).

In conclusion, use `[isEqualTo]` and not `==` -> `if([spriteType isEqualToString:@"typeOne"])`

Comment: your problem is not the same as in your question.  That error occurs when you try to access deallocated memory, so something is wrong with the variable.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use the == operator for strings. Use

```
if [string1 isEqualToString:string2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `randomSpriteNumber = arc4random() % 2+1;` does what you think? In Objective C, the "+" has a higher precedence than the modulus operator (see http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_2.0_Operator_Precedence), so that's effectively `%3` -- therefore allowing a return of 0, 1, or 2. You don't deal with 0.